# Ifelse conditional statement

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

What I want to do is to look in the column `sp` and replace the value “Gaidropsaurus vulgaris” with “Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma” or viceversa, depending on the value of `depth` (`>=148 m`). All other values of `sp` should remain unchanged. I think I need a (possible) nested `ifelse` statement like this:

```
ifelse (dfrm$depth >=148, "Gaidropsaurus macrophthalmus", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris")
```

I have a database with 3 variables: year, species and depth.

```
year <- c("2000", "2000", "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1998", "1998", "2000",
 "1998", "2000", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999", "2000",  "1998", "1998", "1998", "2000", "1998", "1999", "1998", "2000", "1998",  "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999") 

sp <- c("Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gadiculus argenteus",  "Gadiculus argenteus", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Micromesistius poutassou",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Merluccius merluccius",   "Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gadiculus argenteus",  "Gadiculus argenteus", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Micromesistius poutassou",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",  "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",  "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma")

depth <- c("77", "111", "456", "123", "389", "211", "244", "176", "198", "88", "118", "96", "117", "256", "193", "379", "201", "144", "193", "137", "188", "256", "193", "379", "201", "345", "100", "139", "222", "345", "675",  "67", "177")

dfrm <- data.frame (year, sp, depth)
```

The problem is that all the approaches I tried didn't leave the other species alone and changed the other name species to numbers. I know that I could subset Gaidropsaurus species, change the “sp” value using ifelse and then merge it with the rest of the species, but I'm sure there's a better, faster or more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that all the approaches I tried didn´t leave the other species alone and changed the other name species to numbers.

Because `sp` is a factor so we need first to change `sp` to character class as below, then we can do a normal `ifelse`.

```
dfrm$sp<- as.character(dfrm$sp)

dfrm$sp_new <- ifelse (dfrm$sp=='Gaidropsaurus vulgaris' & dfrm$depth >=148, 
                 "Gaidropsaurus macrophthalmus", dfrm$sp)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, then this is what you need:

```
dfrm$sp <- ifelse(dfrm$depth >= 148,
                  ifelse(dfrm$sp == "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",
                         "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",
                         ifelse(dfrm$sp == "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",
                                "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",
                                dfrm$sp)),
                  dfrm$sp)
```

It will first check for the depth condition, then check for the "Gaidropsaurus" species and swap the values, else keep it unchanged

Edit: You will also need to make sure that the variables are of the correct data types. So before you run the above ifelse, run this:
`dfrm$sp <- as.character(dfrm$sp)
 dfrm$depth <- as.numeric(as.character(dfrm$depth))`

Comment: I've done it this time, but you should edit your answer to make sure all important info is in the answer, not the comments.

Comment: Thank you very much @A. Suliman and SmitM for your valuable help. It works :) The trick was in the data type. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, you are asking how to

- Replace each string in the "sp" vector with "Gaidropsaurus
  macropthalmus" if "depth" at that index is >= 148.
- Replace each string in the "sp" vector with "Gaidropsaurus
  vulgaris" if "depth" at that index is < 148.

If so, then creating the data frame you want just requires the following two steps.

1) As you did in your question, assign your data.

```
year <- c("2000", "2000", "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1998", "1998", "2000",  "1998", "2000", "1998", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999", "2000",  "1998", "1998", "1998", "2000", "1998", "1999", "1998", "2000", "1998",  "1999", "1999", "2000", "2000", "1999", "1999")
sp <- c("Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gadiculus argenteus",  "Gadiculus argenteus", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Micromesistius poutassou",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Merluccius merluccius",   "Merluccius merluccius", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gadiculus argenteus",  "Gadiculus argenteus", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Micromesistius poutassou",  "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",  "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Micromesistius poutassou", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris",  "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris", "Gaidropsaurus macrophtalma")
depth <- c("77", "111", "456", "123", "389", "211", "244", "176", "198", "88",     "118", "96", "117", "256", "193", "379", "201", "144", "193", "137", "188", "256", "193", "379", "201", "345", "100", "139", "222", "345", "675",  "67", "177")
```

2) Then add the following two lines of code.

```
sp <- ifelse(depth >= 148,"Gaidropsaurus macrophthalmus", "Gaidropsaurus vulgaris")
dfrm <- data.frame(year,sp,depth)
```

I assume that you wish for your variables "year" and "depth" to be factors (because of the way you assigned these numbers as strings in your data). If so, these variables will be classed as factors in the data frame created above.  Otherwise, if you wanted these variables to be classed as numbers, you could "as.numeric" those variables in your data frame, to make them numeric.